# Como calcular a proporção de proporção texto para o "HTML" ("HTML ratio")?

Tags: seo, independente-de-linguagem

O texto de um "HTML ratio" se refere a quantidade de texto em uma página contra o código da mesma página.

Como fazer esse calculo, sei que devo ter que pegar o DOM provavelmente, mas a parte exatamente quais elementos e como funciona o caculo?

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/dom-monster-bookmarklet-tool/

Comment: Quase a resposta, realmente ficou bem facil de entender, muito agradecido :) - Vou tentar implementar aqui e talvez em breve eu poste uma resposta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### O que é HTML Ratio ou HTML Text Ratio?

O HTML ratio nada mais é do que a porcentagem de texto real em sua página html.
 Em uma página HTML temos o Texto e o Código HTML, o rateio é o porcentagem de texto na página (código + texto real). Uma simples regra de três seria:

```
code  ------- 100%
textoReal --- x

ratio = x;
```

Por exemplo, ao carregar uma página ela tem o tamanho de 80kb. Ao calcular os textos dessa página, podemos ver que desses 80kb, 60kb é apenas de código (tags html, e tudo mais escrito que não seja texto puro) e de texto real ele tem apenas 20kb. Logo, teríamos a 20% de texto. Esse é o nosso Code Rate.

```
 80 ------- 100%
 20 ------- x

 ratio = (20 * 100) / 80;
 ratio = 25%;
```

### Ok, sei o que é isso, mas qual a utilidade disso?

Bom, alguns mecanismos de buscas utilizam o html ratio para indexar o seu site.
Se não bastasse uma melhor posição no Google, por exemplo, ter um bom rateio ajuda nas [SERP's](http://www.marketingdebusca.com.br/voce-sabe-o-que-e-uma-serp/) (A forma que em que sua página aparece, geralmente o título e duas ou três linhas de descrição).

### E como eu faço para calcular isso em meu site?

Então, fazer sua própria ferramenta para calcular pode dar um pouco de trabalho, e pode não ser viável para você. Uma alternativa seria usar alguns serviços, como o [Dom Monster](http://mir.aculo.us/dom-monster/) que o [@LuizVieira comentou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124069/como-calcular-a-propor%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-propor%C3%A7%C3%A3o-texto-para-o-html-html-ratio#comment258937_124069), ou alguns outros, como o [SeoChat](http://tools.seochat.com/tools/code-to-text-ratio/) e o [SmallSeoTools](http://smallseotools.com/code-to-text-ratio-checker/).

### Mas qual a quantidade adequada para o meu site?

Não existe um padrão a ser seguido, até porque não se sabe como é o algorítimo de busca e o que ele utiliza para indexar as páginas, mas o aconselhado é algo em torno de 20 à 80% de sua página.

### Pronto, alterei o rateio de minha página para a porcentagem, agora meu site será o primeiro?

Não, o rateio de texto é apenas um dos fatores para indexação, e não é utilizado por todos os mecanismos, e não se sabe a relevância do mesmo. O melhor para garantir um bom lugar, é ter um bom conteúdo e aplicar as demais prátias de [seo](/questions/tagged/seo) que existem.

> Lembre que da mesma forma que você aplica práticas de **seo**, outros programadores também aplicam. Não é só usar **seo** em seu site que irá garantir uma boa indexação.

Comment: Ao que andei lendo e testando, na maioria das páginas a porcentagem é abaixo de 20%, isso devido a menus e frameworks como Bootstrap que as vezes faz necessitarmos usar mais tags, com isso e somando GoogleAnalitycs, Googlemaps (que gera varios elementos) e conversões do Google dificilmente irá passar de 20%.